# Simple site access analytics with Spring Boot on AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, elastic-beanstalk, analytics, springboot

I have successfully set up a Spring Boot application, deployed as an executable JAR, on AWS Elastic Beanstalk. It has a load balancer with a maximum of 2 (for now) EC2 instances and uses HTTPS. It appears Elastic Beanstalk has set up the EC2 instances to use NGINX as the web server.

Now how is the simplest way to track how many people access the site? This question has variations, of course: How many retrievals were there per page? How many unique IP addresses access all the pages? etc. I'll settle for answering any of these questions to get started.

There seem to be a lot of options and configurations for metrics versus log analysis. There is CloudWatch, CloudWatch Logs, CloudTrail, Kinesis, ElasticSearch, QuickSight, Athena, Kibana … the list goes on. And I'm sure once I'm an expert in analytics I'll understand how to set up an intricate data flow with all sorts of data inputs and visualization options.

But to get started **what is the simplest way to get some initial web access analytics form my Spring Boot deployment on AWS Elastic Beanstalk?** Note that I do not want to add additional tracking mechanisms to the pages such as JavaScript and additional cookies at the moment. I would hope that the EC2 servers and/or the load balancer are producing sufficient logs for such simple analytics.